# Is it correct to say "collect puzzle (jigsaw)"?

Tags: phrases, translation, russian, mistranslation

Fun fact: there is no word for "Jigsaw puzzle" in Russian, so the English word "[Пазл](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CF%E0%E7%EB)" is used. "Собирать" means collect (berries) or assemble (from parts). "Collect puzzle" seems like a direct translation from "Собирать пазл".

I feel that a better way to say it in English would be "Solve the Jigsaw puzzle", but I want to know if "collect puzzle" is also acceptable.

Comment: *Assemble the puzzle* would be more readily understood.

Comment: "Collect" is not the translation for "собирать". What are you even on about.

Comment: Also, what do you mean, there is no Russian word for jugsaw puzzle. There is one. And you mention it yourself. It's пазл. That is a Russian word. It is not an English word.

Comment: at our house people ask if you want to ***do a [jigsaw] puzzle***.  And when it’s done, someone might remark, “Wow.  You ***finished it*** already?!”  if someone *collects* jigsaw puzzles you might ask them how many they have and what’s their oldest or most unusual one.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that any English speaker will understand what a "collect puzzle" is.  A [Google ngram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=collect%20puzzle%2C%20jigsaw%20puzzle&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cjigsaw%20puzzle%3B%2Cc0) shows that the term is not found in their corpus of books.

"Collect" is a strange word for the concept in English, in any event.  You aren't **collecting** the pieces, since you have them all in the box when you buy the puzzle.  You are **arranging** the pieces.

Comment: What would be the correct way to say it?

Comment: As you wrote - "solve the jigsaw puzzle", or as @lbf writes - "put together the jigsaw puzzle".

Answer (score 1):

In Ame concerning a jigsaw puzzle:

Let's **[put together](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/put+together)** a jigsaw puzzle! Yay! Ugh!

> To construct; create: put together a new bookcase; put together a tax
>   package.

As in:

> “Puzzle” is based on a 2010 Argentine film in which another thwarted
>   wife and mother discovers a latent talent for **putting together**
>   jigsaw puzzles. Washington PostJul 31, 2018

and

> She began playing around with different possibilities for how to solve
>   the puzzle—she rearranged their order; she drew them combined with one
>   another like **putting together** a jigsaw puzzle.

In AmE, 'collect puzzle' or even 'collect a puzzle' would not be used.